# Trying to use CMD-command in python script with "subprocess.run()"

Tags: python, .net-core, cmd, subprocess

I am trying to run a program I can only access through the CMD in a python script:

```
command = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\chatbot.Cli\\dotnet chatbot.Cli.dll export -f PlainText -p 140 -o "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\xxx.txt" --after "2023-05-18 09:00"'

subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

The error I am getting is the following:
'C:\Users\xxx\Documents\chatbot.Cli\dotnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

.NET 7.0 is installed and when I run the exact same command on the CMD it works perfectly fine.
Does anyone have an idea why?

Thank you :)

Comment: Please read the Python documentation for the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if not already done. The `subprocess` module is on Windows a Python wrapper module (=dynamically loaded library like a DLL) for the Windows kernel library function [CreateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessw) called without or with a [STARTUPINFO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfow) structure to run an executable.

Comment: `shell=True` results in calling `CreateProcess` to run `%ComSpec%` expanding usually to `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` with option `/c` and the command line defined as string in the Python script appended as additional arguments for execution by the Windows *Command Processor* and close itself after finishing that. `cmd.exe` uses also `CreateProcess` to run executables. The difference between running an executable with `cmd.exe` using `shell=True` and running an executable directly with `subprocess.run()` is that the Python programmer does not have control over how `CreateProcess` is called.

Comment: It is therefore usually wrong by design to use `subprocess.run()` with `shell=True` as whatever `cmd.exe` should execute can be executed also directly by the Python script using `subprocess.run()` or `subprocess.Popen()`. The argument 0 of the command line to process by `cmd.exe` is `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\chatbot.Cli\dotnet`. We don't know if `xxx` contains perhaps a space character (argument string separator) which requires enclosing the argument string in `"` as it is necessary for any argument string containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~<>|``.

Comment: It is also possible that `xxx` contains a non ASCII character on which the character encoding used on writing the Python script and the character encoding (code page) used by `cmd.exe` on interpreting the command line would matter and could be a reason for executable not found by `cmd.exe`. The Windows *Command Processor* interprets `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\chatbot.Cli\dotnet` as executable/script to run and searches first for `dotnet` and next for `dotnet.com`, `dotnet.exe`, ... according to file extensions list as defined in local environment variable `PATHEXT` in the specified directory.

Comment: `cmd` cannot find a suitable file resulting in the error message instead of calling `CreateProcess` with function parameter `lpApplicationName` pointing to the string `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\chatbot.Cli\dotnet.exe` or whatever would be the correct fully qualified executable file name. However, this is an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). There is no need using `subprocess.run()` for calling `CreateProcess` with `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` as **application name** and `/c` plus the other argument strings as defined in the Python script as **command line**.

Comment: The Python script can call `CreateProcess` with `subprocess.run()` to run directly `C:\Users\xxx\Documents\chatbot.Cli\dotnet.exe` (**application name**) with `chatbot.Cli.dll export -f PlainText -p 140 -o "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\xxx.txt" --after "2023-05-18 09:00"` as arguments (**command line**). BTW: `chatbot.Cli.dll` is referenced without path which means with a path relative to __current directory__. Have you used `cwd="..."` in Python script to make sure the current working directory is the directory containing the DLL file `chatbot.Cli.dll`? It does not look so.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your comments Mofi, I just found the error:

```
command = 'dotnet C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\chatbot.Cli\\chatbot.Cli.dll export -f PlainText -p 140 -o "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Documents\\xxx.txt" --after "2023-05-18 09:00"'

subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

This is working for me, I did not reference the path for the chatbot.Cli.dll. I thought the reference in front of the dotnet command would be enough.
Thanks!